# I have a problem with login in shopify cli when i run "npm run dev"

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, shopify

- Hello everyone , I have some issues with shopify cli,

When i run npm run dev, the console shows that i have to click to get into the login page

when i login, the login is succesfull but in command line it tells an error:

what should i do?

```
│                                                                                                    │
│  request to                                                                                        │
│  https://accounts.shopify.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=34586bf29242d27255a8  │
│  176ebef450f5a9a007bb291bf2b1b3e8168e7612c0ce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3456&client_i  │
│  d=fbdb2649-e327-4907-8f67-908d24cfd7e3&code_verifier=pF82_4kdVu2JZM01n-v9u2xFgbYeMUj-0Ret8LJOyBM  │
│   failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.10.34.35:443                                                │
│                                                                                                    │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

I expect it to login in the terminal and i did try admin cmd, i tried with vpn and without vpn
but it didn't worked

Comment: Do you use VPN?